# Increase sensibility using collision detection in sphero api

Tags: sphero-api

I'm wanting to do a maze solver program using sphero and artoo, so I need to detect collision in low speed and with a very high sensibility.

I've been looking at Collision detection docs: https://github.com/orbotix/DeveloperResources/blob/master/docs/Collision%20detection%201.2.pdf

Could help me to figure out what params to ConfigureCollisionDetection I should use? http://grab.by/vWLI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to want very low values for Xt, Yt, Xspd, and Yspd. Try setting Xt and Yt to something < 100 and your speeds to something less than what you are commanding the ball to do.